# Pyqt5 plot not updated?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Plotting is working fine however it does not update when new information is plotted ?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,width=5,height=4,dpi=100):
        fig=Figure(figsize=(width,height),dpi=dpi)
        self.axes=fig.add_subplot(111)
        super().__init__(fig)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
  def __init__(self, data):
      super().__init__()
      self._data = data
  def data(self, index, role):
      if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
          value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
          return str(value)
  def rowCount(self, index):
      return self._data.shape[0]
  def columnCount(self, index):
      return self._data.shape[1]
  def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
      if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return str(self._data.columns[section])
        if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
            return str(self._data.index[section])


     
class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        loadUi("untitled.ui",self)

        self.setWindowTitle("SwarmDynamics Equity Curve Builder")
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        conn=sqlite3.connect('D:\Qt\Test\\GBPUSD.db')
        data=pd.read_sql('Select * from Data',conn)
        data['Sum']=data['Delta_Equity_Adjusted'].sum()
        systems=pd.read_sql('SELECT DISTINCT System from Data',conn)
        conn.close()
        ###########
        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.add)
        ##############
        self.selected_system.addItems(list(systems['System']))
        #self.selected_system.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.index_changed)
        self.selected_system.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
       
        
    def index_changed(self, i): # i is an int
        print(i)
    def text_changed(self, s): # s is a str
        print('Plotting new graph :' + s)
        conn=sqlite3.connect('D:\Qt\Test\\GBPUSD.db')
        data=pd.read_sql('Select Total_Equity from Data where System=\"' + s + '\"',conn)
        conn.close()
        
        sc=MplCanvas(self,width=5,height=4,dpi=100)
        
        data['Total_Equity'].plot(ax=sc.axes)
        layout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(sc)
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        
        
        
        
    def update_plot(self):
        self.sc.axes.cla()
        #self.sc.draw()

        

       

        #self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.MplWidget.canvas, self))
    def add(self):
        print ('pish')
        #self.textBrowser.insertPlainText('Loading data for symbol ')


   
        

app = QApplication([])
app.setStyle('Fusion')
window = MatplotlibWidget()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you are trying to update the plot by fully recreating the MplCanvas. It would be more efficient to only create the canvas once and keep it while updating the plot with its draw-method.

I have boiled down your code to a minimal working example, which should deliver the idea:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super().__init__(fig)

class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Update Plot")
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        # canvas gets created during init once
        self.sc = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        layout.addWidget(self.sc)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.update_plot()
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.show()

    def update_plot(self):
        # new data is plotted
        self.sc.axes.cla()
        data = np.array(np.random.random(3))
        self.sc.axes.plot(data)
        # canvas gets updated by redrawing (if this line is omitted, nothing gets updated
        self.sc.draw()

app = QApplication([])
window = MatplotlibWidget()
app.exec_()
```